# Explicit dereference of function pointer In C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a piece of code which is an example of function pointer and have taken from Linux Kernel source .Below is the structure having callback function as its member

```
 struct parport_driver {
 const char *name;
 void (*attach) (struct parport *);
 struct parport_driver *next;
 };
```

Now member of these structure is called in C file like given below

```
 struct parport_driver *drv;

 drv->attach(port); /* calling function through implicit dereference */
```

Above function is called in implicit way but i want to know how it would be called explicit way.

What is difference between implicit and explicit way of dereferencing function pointer.

One more thing I would like to know structure member attach should be intialized before a call (drv->attach(port));

Somehing like

drv->attach=attach_driver_chain;

where attach_driver_chain is function but I could not find any such intialization in driver code.

Answer (score 7):

The postfix `()` operator (function call) is defined to take a pointer to a function and call the function. So it is an explicit dereference of the pointer. There is no other way to call a function.

Although `(*FunctionPointer)()` looks like an explicit dereference, the type of the expression `*FunctionPointer` is a function. Per C 2011 6.3.2.1 4, an expression of function type is converted to a pointer to the function (except when the expression is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or `&`). So, in `(*FunctionPointer)()`, `*FunctionPointer` is converted to be the same as `FunctionPointer` and nothing has been accomplished: The expression is the same as before, and the `()` operator acts on a function pointer, not a function.

There is no difference between calling a function with `FunctionPointer()` and calling it with `(*FunctionPointer)()`. You could even write `(***************FunctionPointer)()` with the same effect. Each of the `*` operators will be nullified by the automatic conversion.

Answer (score 4):

> Above function is called in implicit way but wanted to know how it would be called explicit way.

Like this:

```
(*(drv->attach))(port); // Not very pretty, huh?
```

> What is difference between implicit and explicit way of dereferencing function pointer

There is no difference: since all you can do with a function pointer is call a function that it points to, compiler ignores explicit dereferences of function pointers.

Comment: Actually, `drv->attach(port)` is an explicit dereferencing of the function pointer; the postfix `()` is defined to take a pointer to a function and to call it. In the code in this answer, `*(drv->attach)` produces an expression with function type. This is automatically converted back to a pointer to the function. So the `()` operator acts on the same thing in this code as it did in the original.

Comment: @EricPostpischil could you please explain it in your answer?

Answer (score -1):

This example may help also

```
struct product
{
    string name;
    int weight;
    double price;
};

product *p1 = new product();
(*p1).name = "orange"; // This is an explicit dereferencing
p1->name = "orange";   // This is also an explicit dereferencing

product *p2 = &p1;
p2.name = "apple"; // This is an implicit dereferencing
```